# realizar update en una tabla en oracle usando php

Tags: php, oracle

estoy realizando un proyecto en php pero no me permite realizar un update en una tabla ya lo intente varias veces y me sale el mismo error

```html
Warning: oci_parse() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in gpersonal.clase.php on line 18 
Warning: oci_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in gpersonal.clase.php on line 19 
Warning: oci_commit() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in gpersonal.clase.php on line 20
```

el metodo que estoy usando es

```html
$update="UPDATE T_RIESGO SET N_GPMS = 3 WHERE N_CODRIESGO= 1";
        
$stmt = oci_parse($bd, $update);
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
oci_commit($bd);
```

Las columnas N_GPMS Y N_CODRIESGO son number

podrian ayudarme por favor ya intente de varia maneras y no logro que funcione correctamnete

Comment: Al parecer la conexión no se está creando bien. Puedes verificarlo de este modo: `if ($bd) { $stmt = oci_parse($bd, $update);
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
oci_commit($bd); echo "¡Actualización realizada!"; } else { echo "Hubo un error al crear la conexión a la BD"; }` Para más detalles, ver las indicaciones del [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php)

Answer (score 0):

No se si te falto pegar el codigo de conexion o que contiene el $bd, pero este debe de realizar la conexion de esta forma:

```
$bd = oci_connect("userName","password","hostName");
```

de ser posible y lo mas recomendado es que generes validación de que si quedo bien realizada la conexión

```
if ($bd=oci_connect("username", "password", "hostName")){
    echo "Successfully connected to Oracle.\n";
  } else {
    $err = OCIError();
    echo "Oracle Connect Error " . $err[text];
  }
```

Comment: La conexión a la base de datos funciona correctamente ya que puedo realizar las demás consultas con normalidad y también le puse varia validaciones pero me sigue devolviendo el mismo error